# Error is not View Result tree but It is displaying in sumary report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I was executing load testing on my application, after execution I analysis View result tree and Summary Report in listener, and found Summary report is showing error %  for some sampler but View result tree is showing them green.
What can be general reason both listener is showing different result?

Comment: Did you clean-all before running again? JMeter aggregates result from past runs if you don't.

Comment: Yes I have cleaned and also It was first time when I am executing test plan.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Errors and Successes check-box are unchecked in View Results Tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) doesn't show all the results, by default it shows only last 500 entries so it might be the case it "hides" the ones which have failed.

The setting is controllable by the `view.results.tree.max_results` property, try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

and restart JMeter, once done the View Results Tree listener should display all the sample results (if they fit into the memory)

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference - Miscellaneous configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)